# Computing pixel spatial resolution (in mm) from intrinsic camera matrix and known object depth

Tags: opencv, graphics, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Assume I have an intrinsic camera matrix K that describes a focal length (in pixels) and x and y offsets (also in pixels). Given this matrix K as well as the depth (in mm) of a pixel in my image, is it possible to determine the pixel resolution in mm of each pixel in my image?

I'd like to know the dimensions in real-space that each square pixel represents. So 1 square pixel might represent an area of 10mm x 10mm in real space at a depth of 25mm.

My current approach:

`[u, v, z] = np.dot(K, [x, y, z, 1])`

Where `K = np.asarray([[f_x, 0, c_x, 0], [0, f_y, c_y, 0], [0, 0, 1 0]])` in pixels and `[u, v]` are the x,y pixel coordinates in the image.

To determine the spatial resolution of the each pixel, I can use the inverse of the camera matrix `K_inv` and a known depth `z` to determine the location of the pixel in 3D space:

`[x, y, z, 1] = np.dot(K_inv, [u, v, z])`

And repeat this process for a change in pixel value:

`[x_1, y, z, 1] = np.dot(K_inv, [(u+ 1), v, z])`

The difference `|x_1 - x|` is the horizontal resolution in mm (hopefully) of each pixel. Assuming square pixels, then each pixel represents an area in real-space of `|x_1 - x|` * `|x_1 - x|` square mm that is projected onto 1 square pixel?

Comment: yes, it is possible. -- please review [ask]. show your attempt, present your reasoning. all of this just involves math on a right triangle.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz edited per comments, but I didn't use right triangles, so I'm not sure this is correct?

Comment: Do you want the physical size of one pixel or the real-life size corresponding to what is projected on the pixel ?

Comment: @Lelouch The real life size corresponding to what is projected on the pixel. Will edit to clarify. Thanks for the question!